# Why exim reads certificate and key from the same file?

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, configuration, exim

I configured SSL by adding these strings to `01_exim4-config_listmacrosdefs`. I use split configuration

```
MAIN_TLS_ENABLE = yes
MAIN_TLS_CERTKEY = /etc/exim4/example.com.crt
MAIN_TLS_PRIVATEKEY = /etc/exim4/example.com.key
```

So after restarting, connecting to port 465, typing `EHLO` and `STARTTLS` I got this: `454 TLS currently unavailable`

In the log I have this:

```
13:29:36 10872 SMTP<< STARTTLS
13:29:36 10872 initialising GnuTLS as a server
13:29:36 10872 GnuTLS global init required.
13:29:36 10872 initialising GnuTLS server session
13:29:36 10872 Expanding various TLS configuration options for session credentials.
13:29:36 10872 certificate file = /etc/exim4/example.com.crt
13:29:36 10872 key file = /etc/exim4/example.com.crt
13:29:36 10872 LOG: MAIN
13:29:36 10872   TLS error on connection from (192.168.1.111) [91.210.44.50] (cert/key setup: cert=/etc/exim4/example.com.crt key=/etc/exim4/example.com.crt): Error in parsing.
```

Why does exim use the same file both for certificate and key? How to fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I should have used `MAIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE` instead of `MAIN_TLS_CERTKEY`.

Answer (score 1):

@chicks I'd upvote if serverfault would let me.

Still snagging people (i.e., me over two years later).

Technically, the comments in `conf.d/main/03_exim4-config_tlsoptions` say that if you have the certificate and key in the *same* file, then use `MAIN_TLS_CERTKEY`. That's bad practice but allowed.

```
#   MAIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE - path to certificate file,
#                          CONFDIR/exim.crt if unset
#   MAIN_TLS_PRIVATEKEY  - path to private key file
#                          CONFDIR/exim.key if unset
# You can also configure exim to look for certificate and key in the
# same file, set MAIN_TLS_CERTKEY to that file to enable. This takes
# precedence over all other settings regarding certificate and key file.
```

I glossed over that and went straight to the `ifdef` statements. The first of those is:

```
.ifdef MAIN_TLS_CERTKEY
```

and I completely missed the `.else` part:

```
.ifdef MAIN_TLS_CERTKEY
tls_certificate = MAIN_TLS_CERTKEY
.else
.ifndef MAIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE
MAIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE = CONFDIR/exim.crt
.endif
tls_certificate = MAIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE
```

TL;DR: Yes, set `MAIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE` rather than `MAIN_TLS_CERTKEY`.